# Sync Azure SQL Database with remote database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I was wondering if someone could help. I have a SQL database hosted on a remote server (internet hosting company) and i want to sync my azure database.

any ideas how i could do this? eventually, i would like to transition over to sql azure.

thanks in advance.

Comment: is it a one time transition or will you have both databases co-existing and synchronizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i prefer using SQL Database Migration Wizard: http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/ for one time migrations. it has the option to do some analysis to check for things that are not supported in Azure SQL Database.